# change width of divs depending on the number of divs on page with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, arrays, dynamic

UPDATE: Revised and edited some of those obvious problems you all pointed out below. Am I getting warmer?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   var totaldivs = $('.feature').length;

   if (totaldivs == 3){

removeClass().addClass('three-features');

   } else if(totaldivs == 2){

removeClass().addClass('two-features');

   } 

});
```

---

I'm new to JavaScript/JQuery so maybe what I'm trying to do here is tragically flawed but I'd like to craft a script that checks to see how many divs of a certain class are on a page and change the width of those divs based on the number that are present. I plan to do this by changing the divs' class to one with a different width after checking the length of the array of divs.

**Where am I going wrong here?**

I know I'll have to figure out another solution for getElementsByClassName in IE.

**Here's my js:**

```
var totaldivs = document.getElementsByClassName('feature');

$(document).ready(function(){

    if (features.length==3){

    $('.features').removeClass().addClass('three-features');

  } else if(features.length==2){

    $('.features').removeClass().addClass('two-features');

  } 

});
```

**And here's my css**

```
.feature {
float: left;
}
.two-features {
float: left;
width: 100px;
}
.three-features {
float: left;
width: 50px;
}
```

Comment: For one, you using totaldivs as a variable, then you're using features instead. Which will be null.

Comment: you never use `totaldivs`.  `feature` or `features` ? never specified the class to remove `removeClass()`

Comment: @JayHarris: Passing no argument to `.removeClass()` removes all of the classes.

Comment: @Blender assuming he has no other classes set in that div, then my statement should be ignored

Comment: totaldivs = $('feature').length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you assign the totaldivs afterthe document is ready.

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    var totaldivs = $('.feature').length;
    // and do something smarter like @Blender pointed out
}
```

PS:
Styling with Jquery is always a bad idea and it kills you when your app expands. 
Consider using css like: 

display:table-cell, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You define `totaldivs` but use `features`, which you don't define. I would just do it like this:

```
var counts = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

$(document).ready(function() {
    var $features = $('.features');
    var className = counts[$features.length - 1] + '-features';

    $features.removeClass().addClass(className);
});
```